# angle chasing in quadrilaterals

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, euclidean-geometry, circles, quadrilateral

> Let $ABCD$ be a convex quadrilateral
>
> with 
>   $\measuredangle{ABD} = 18^{\circ}$, $\measuredangle{ACB} = 54^{\circ}$,
>   $\measuredangle{ACD} = 36^{\circ}$ and 
>   $\measuredangle{ADB} = 27^{\circ}$.
>
> Let $\{P\}$
>   be the intersection of the two diagonals $AC$ and $BD$.
>
> What is the degree value of $\measuredangle{APB}$?

[image]

Comment: I have added a figure made with Geogebra.

Comment: thank you. This question really confuses me. I am now trying to find sin36 degrees and use law of sine now... Is there a smart way to do this?

Comment: A technical remark that will allow you simpler computations is to replace all your angle values by 2a,3a,4a,6a, with a=9°, keeping in mind that 10a=90° for simplifications.

Comment: yeah that make this a lot easier... Thank you!

Comment: um this is still somehow confusing. Can you give me another hint? Thank you.

Comment: give the names, x,y,z to angles APB, CBD and BDC resp. (x being the value you are looking for). You can notice that $y+z=10a$ by reasoning on the sum of angles in triangle BDC. Find two other equations linking $x,y,z$. You will end up with a system of 3 (linear) equations in the 3 unknowns $x,y,z$ that you will ultimately solve.

Comment: Hint: Prove that C is the circum-center of $\triangle DAB.

Comment: Oops. Should have thought about that.... Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some angle chasing, we have the following:-
[image]

The configuration seems like C is the circum-center of the circle DAB.

Added:-

The tricky part is:- "Is C really the circum-center of $\triangle ABD$?"

[image]

This is done by extending AC to cut the circum-circle at F. Again by angle chasing, we get $\beta = \angle 1 = \angle 2$. This means $\triangle CFB$ is isosceles. The same is true for $\triangle CFD$. Then, point C (not the red dot anymore) is indeed the circum-center of $\triangle ABD$ (because (1) CB = CF = CD and (2) B, F, D are points on the circumference of the same circle).

Finally, we have $\angle CDB = \angle CBD = 45^0$. Result follows.

Comment: um dont it get proved immediately by the subtended arc theorem?

Comment: @Mick If $C$ is a circumcenter it's holds. But why from the given follows that $C$ is a circumcenter?

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg See added.

Comment: @Mick Why $C\in AF$?

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg F is constructed by extending AC to cut the circumcircle at F.

Comment: @Mick Now I see it! Nice solution! +1

Answer (score 3):

Let $CK$ be a bisector of $\Delta ADC$ and $CL$ be a bisector of $\Delta ABC$.

Thus, $KCLA$ is cyclic and from here $\measuredangle KLA=\measuredangle KCA=18^{\circ}=\measuredangle ABD$.

Thus, $KL||DB$, which says $AC:DC=AK:KD=AL:LB=AC:BC$,

which gives $DC=BC$, $\measuredangle CBA=45^{\circ}$ and $\measuredangle APB=54^{\circ}+45^{\circ}=99^{\circ}.$

Comment: I can't follow why KCLA is cyclic after setting CK and CL as (angle) bisectors.

Comment: @Mick Because $\measuredangle KCL+\measuredangle KAL=45^{\circ}+135^{\circ}=180^{\circ}$.

Comment: Uh! I see. Nice solution using angle bisector theorem.  +1

Answer (score 1):

Let S be the center of the circumcircle of triangle ABD. D is a point on that circumcircle, and ∠ADB = 18∘, so therefore, ∠ASD = 36∘. Consider the circumcircle of ASD. S is a point on that circumcircle and ∠ASD = 36∘, so therefore for each point on that circumcircle Q and only for those points, ∠AQD = 36∘ is a true statement.

We know ∠ACD = 36∘, so therefore, C is on the circumcircle of ADS.

Analogically, since ∠BCA = ∠BSA = 2 * ∠BDA = 54∘, C is also on the circumcircle of ABS.

Out of this, we can conclude points C and S are on the intersections of ABS's and ADS's circumcircles. The only such intersections are points A and C. Obviously, S is not the same point as A (otherwise, ∠BDA = ∠DBA would be true), and neither is C (otherwise, ∠ACB = 54∘ makes no sense) so we conclude S is C.

Therefore, C is ABD's circumcenter. Out of that, we can get DC = BC (two radii in the same circle), and by that we conclude BCD is bilateral and ∠DBC = ∠BDC.

We know ∠BCD = 36∘ + 54∘ = 90∘. Therefore , ∠DBC=45∘.

Finally, ∠APB = 54∘ + 45∘ = 99∘.